# Secure WebSocket Server (TLS and wss)

Tags: ssl, websocket, https, wss

I run a static HTTPS page on a webserver providing a valid certificate. On my page, there is a JavaScript creating a websocket connection.

`new WebSocket('wss://IpOfWebsocketServer');`

The first thing the websocket server receives is a request from the client. But the request itself is encrypted! How should the websocket server read the encrypted request?? When a web client connects to the HTTPS page there is made a TLS handshake and everything later is encrypted - also the request to the websocket server is encrypted. But how should the separately running websocket server know the key to decrypt? Can wss websockets run at all?

Everything (HTML page and websocket server) worked fine earlier when I used HTTP and ws. Now I must switch to HTTPS and wss.

Comment: A WSS connection starts out as a standard HTTPS connection, so any HTTPS server should already be handling the TLS handshake and initial HTTP request of the WebSocket handshake for you. Once the WebSocket handshake is finished, the server and client can then exchange WebSocket messages over the existing encrypted connection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know that messages can be exchanged over the websocket after the websocket's handshake. But the websocket server is a separate machine and does not run the HTTPS page. The websocket's handshake must be done between the browser client and the websocket server. But the browser client sends a encrypted (!) request to the websocket server because the browser client is on a HTTPS page. A encrypted connection request is absolutely useless for the independently running websocket server. How should the websocket server read the encryped request?

Answer (score 1):

> The first thing the websocket server receives is a request from the client. But the request itself is encrypted! How should the websocket server read the encrypted request??

The exact same way that an HTTPS server reads encrypted HTTP messages. A TLS session is established between client and server *before* any application data is exchanged.  The TLS session decrypts any data being received, and encrypts any data being sent.

So, an HTTPS client connects to an HTTPS server, negotiates a TLS session first, and then exchanges HTTP messages that are encrypted/decrypted by that TLS session.

The exact same thing happens with WebSockets, too.  A WSS client connects to an WSS server, negotiates a TLS session first, then negotiates the WebSocket handshake using HTTP messages (encrypted by TLS), and then exchanges subsequent WebSocket messages (encrypted by TLS).

> When a web client connects to the HTTPS page there is made a TLS handshake and everything later is encrypted

The exact same thing happens for a secure WebSocket connection, too.

> But how should the separately running websocket server know the key to decrypt?

It doesn't know the original key used by the TLS session of the HTTPS page, nor does it need to know.  The WebSocket client will establish a *separate* TLS session with the WebSocket server, with its own key that only the WebSocket client and WebSocket server share with each other.

Note, this is separate from the per-frame masking key that a WebSocket client must use for every frame of data it sends to a WebSocket server after the WebSocket handshake is complete.  That masking key is contained inside of each frame, and is always used even if TLS is not employed to encrypt the underlying connection between client and server.

> Can wss websockets run at all?

Of course.

Comment: I see, the websocket server must do an own TLS handshake. Your answer is very hepful for me! Sadly, I have more problems now. First: Why does the browser client not send something that looks like a TLS hello message to the websocket server? The browser client sends a message that contains special characters and looks different for every request. Second: It was not agreed that a websocket implementation must be able to do a TLS handshake. There is no budget to enhance my implementation. I can kick my system, my business and that secure websockets shit to the moon. I have no workaround :(

Comment: "*the websocket server must do an own TLS handshake*" - yes, every connection uses its own TLS session. "*Why does the browser client not send something that looks like a TLS hello message to the websocket server?*" - it should, unless it reuses an existing connection that is already secured. "*The browser client sends a message that contains special characters and looks different for every request*" - please update your question to show the actual data. "*It was not agreed that a websocket implementation must be able to do a TLS handshake*" - it must if it wants to support WSS connections.